# Windows 7 Auto Size on mouse left?

Tags: windows-7, size

I was wondering on windows 7 there is the function that when your mouse hits the form left/right top it will auto size the window to half the screen. I am trying to do that with my MDI Child. Here is the code that I have, however the function does not work.

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        if (e.X == f1.Width/2 - 30)
        {
            Form activeChild = this.ActiveMdiChild;
            activeChild.Width = this.Width / 2;
            activeChild.Height = this.Height;
            activeChild.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try doing that on the Move event of the actual child form.  Handling the event based on a new instance of Form1 in any event won't work very well.  Anyhow, here's some code as it would look inside the child.  (Ugly, but it at least does something.)

```
    private void SubForm_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Location.X <= 0)
        {
            Width = MdiParent.Width / 2;
            Height = MdiParent.Height;
            Location = new Point(0,0);
            Dock = DockStyle.Left;
        }
    }
```